How to find matching coordinate returned from MySQL, coordinate is in binary form?
I have a MySQL db and it is returning a coordinate in this form b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\xacTPQ\xf5\x8b\t\xc0i\xac\xfd\x9d\xed\xf9K@', I have hundreds of these coordinates and I need to find the one which has an incorrect latitude value of -95.712891
I have tried multiple solutions but they keep returning incorrect values after converting the binary returns
I am looking for a solution I can use to properly convert these values or the correct mySQL binary representation fo the reported incorrect latitude -95.712891
Update
The code that isn't working due to the incorrect latitude value is
conn = pymysql.connect(
    host=endpoint,
    user=username,
    password=password,
    port=port,
    database=database
)

cursor = conn.cursor()

query = """
SELECT uuid, ERASEnabled, useractivity
FROM algoData
WHERE gender = %s
AND dob BETWEEN %s AND %s
AND ST_Distance_Sphere(location, ST_PointFromText(%s)) / 1609.34 <= %s
LIMIT %s;
"""

limit = 5000

parameters = (
    lookingFor,
    min_date_string,
    max_date_string,
    formattedCoordinatesForSQLUse,
    maxDistance,
    limit,
)

The code used to retrieve all binary location points is
conn = pymysql.connect(
        host=endpoint,
        user=username,
        password=password,
        port=port,
        database=database
    )

    cursor = conn.cursor()


    read_command = """
        SELECT *
        FROM algoData
    """

    cursor.execute(read_command)
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    
    uuids = [result[0] for result in results]
    locationPoints = [result[3] for result in results]
    locationPoints = [str(point) for point in locationPoints]

The column description is ('location', 'point', 'NO', 'MUL', None, '')
Any help with this is much appreciated

Please show us the code where you are retrieving the coordinate, and the SQL column declaration.

@StephenC I have added the code and column information

I solved this by getting the X and Y coordinates seperately from the DB instead of getting the entire location in binary form
With MySQL a query similar to
query = """
SELECT ST_X(location), ST_Y(location) FROM your_table;
"""
Where location is your point data type column
